# SP2013 and workflow manager 1.0 (SPOF - High Availability) server Topology

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow-manager, sharepoint-farm

Regardless of the fact that it is not recommended to install workflow manager on SP farm, or the hardware resources.

I want to know, if I installed the SP on **only 3 servers** (all are web front and central administrator run on one of them).
then Installed the workflow manager 1.0 (with client) **on the same 3 servers of SP.**

Can I achieve with this topology the ( **No Single Point Of Failure** ) and High Availability environment ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are running redundant services otherwise -yes you can and it is supported.  In most deployments thus small workflow is in fact normally deployed on the SharePoint servers and run just fine.

Bear in mind services like profile sync and distributed cache are not highly available services.